# Why is Stack Exchange logo written as StackExcha'r'ge?

Tags: support, status-declined, design, stackexchange.com, logo

[image]

The Stack Exchange logo displayed in the top left is written as Stack Excharge. Why? Is it done purposefully or a bug?

Comment: I don't see what you're referring to - every place I've seen the SE logo, it's been spelled correctly.

Comment: I think you'd be better off showing a screenshot of what you're seeing because it looks exactly like "StackExchange" to me... even zoomed out with my not-so-good eyesight

Comment: Sorry about that, edited my question.

Comment: And where exactly do you see that? Please point us to the exact location.

Comment: In the Nav bar.

Comment: Where exactly...?

Comment: Ok, well.... that's not what I expected... The logo is an inline SVG so no idea how that would happen

Comment: What OS, browser version  is that? If you try another browser, does that have the same effect? And if you use a different device? Are you zoomed in / out by any chance?

Comment: Ubuntu 14.04 with Firefox 40.0.3. Checked in Google chrome, displays fine.

Comment: FF 40 is ... really, really, really old ...

Comment: ikr ;) I use it with Selenium and didn't want to upgrade. So I've disabled updates.

Comment: SE supports in general the current release and the previous release. If that bug doesn't repro in recent versions this will be no fix.

Comment: Cannot reproduce this in Chrome 65, 64-bit, Windows 7 - I see a correct spelling.

Comment: I don't understand why this is closed as *can no longer be reproduced*. Has any of the close voters installed FF40, awaited a new build from SE and re-verified? I don't buy that. Nothing has changed, the bug is still there for the OP. It sure needs a status-declined or status-nofix, but the close reason is rubbish, re-open vote casted.

Comment: @rene well, can't be reproduced using a *supported browser*. But yeah, probably wrong to close.

Comment: FF40 is not safe to use on the public internet. No really old browsers are, they all have known exploitable security bugs. If you want to use FF40 make sure you only use it on an intranet.

Comment: @rene I voted to close as no repro. It's not reproducible with any supported browser. Otherwise we could post a million issues with SE on whatever old platform we like. (Netscape ftw)

Comment: @Rory well, ideal usage of that close reason is when a feature or bug "becomes void" due to change in SE, e.g. all open requests/bug reports about accept rate or the old profile design. Using this reason for things like browser versions feels indeed bit wrong to me. (Voted anyway, but will probably not do it again)

Comment: It doesn't need to be closed.  It's marked as [status-declined] which is all that needs to be done with it.  There's no harm in leaving it open.  The only reason to close it would be if it was a duplicate.

Comment: I have retracted my close vote then. Thanks for the further explanation.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There was a [bug in old Firefox versions](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1356179) which caused certain parts of SVG to not show.

It's illustrated [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q20Jm.png) pretty well.

Most likely that's the source of what you saw. Just use a modern updated browser.

Comment: That bug is about thin lines not displaying though and that’s not what’s happening here

Comment: @Cai why not? The logo is SVG, they build the letters with blocks of text, the "n" letter is also built with some markup. Old FF fail to render this markup correctly for some reason.

Comment: that bug is specifically about thin lines; the bit that is missing isn’t a thin line but a filled area. I’m not saying it isn’t a bug, it’s just not *that* bug

Comment: As Robert Longson is both active here and on the SVG subsystem for FF I'm sure he'll confirm.

Comment: @Cai it's too similar to be just a coinicedence, if not this specific bug then surely a related, maybe older, bug.

Comment: If anyone was bothered they could investigate using [mozregression](https://mozilla.github.io/mozregression/). That could well be the right bug though.

Comment: Yes ! On zooming in twice, it displays 'StackExchange'. On zooming further, its back to 'StackExharge'. Perhaps the same issue. Thank you everyone for chipping in your thoughts.

Answer (score 8):

I expect this bug will not be looked into further, as the logo displays correctly on all supported browsers, and you've indicated you're using an unsupported browser.

Please see [Which browsers are officially supported, and what else do I need?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56161/which-browsers-are-officially-supported-and-what-else-do-i-need) for information on which browsers are supported on these sites, and consider switching to a supported browser if you are finding issues that prevent normal site usage.

If you find this bug in a supported browser please create a new question and provide the browser version and screenshots demonstrating the bug.